# How to call MSBuild from C#

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Is there a better way to call MSBuild from C#/.NET than shelling out to the msbuild.exe? If yes, how?

Comment: Related question (but uses Powershell instead of raw C#) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472038/how-to-run-msbuild-from-powershell-without-spawning-msbuild-exe-process/473629

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, add a reference to `Microsoft.Build.Engine` and use the [Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.aspx) class.

PS: Take care to reference the right version. There are 2.0 and 3.5 assemblies and you'll have to [make sure that everyone gets the right one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/2772a075-4e2f-42af-9e7a-2228b794368e/).

Answer (score 16):

For a .NET 2.0-specific version, you can use the following:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
engine.BinPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
    + @"\..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";

FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
logger.Parameters = @"logfile=C:\temp\test.msbuild.log";
engine.RegisterLogger(logger);

string[] tasks = new string[] { "MyTask" };
BuildPropertyGroup props = new BuildPropertyGroup();
props.SetProperty("parm1","hello Build!");

try
{
  // Call task MyTask with the parm1 property set
  bool success = engine.BuildProjectFile(@"C:\temp\test.msbuild",tasks,props);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // your error handler
}
finally
{
 engine.UnregisterAllLoggers();
 engine.UnloadAllProjects();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Microsoft.Build.Engine.Engine`, you'll get a warning: `This class has been deprecated. Please use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection from the Microsoft.Build assembly instead.`

Now, the proper way to run MSBuild from C# looks like this:

```
public sealed class MsBuildRunner
{

    public bool Run(FileInfo msbuildFile, string[] targets = null, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null, LoggerVerbosity loggerVerbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed)
    {
        if (!msbuildFile.Exists) throw new ArgumentException("msbuildFile does not exist");

        if (targets == null)
        {
            targets = new string[] {};
        }
        if (properties == null)
        {
            properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Running {0} targets: {1} properties: {2}, cwd: {3}",
                              msbuildFile.FullName,
                              string.Join(",", targets),
                              string.Join(",", properties),
                              Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        var project = new Project(msbuildFile.FullName, properties, "4.0");
        return project.Build(targets, new ILogger[] { new ConsoleLogger(loggerVerbosity) });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the path to the MSBuild tools folder, you can use the [`ToolLocationHelper` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.toollocationhelper.aspx) from the Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core assembly:

```
var toolsetVersion = ToolLocationHelper.CurrentToolsVersion;
var msbuildDir = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToBuildTools(toolsetVersion);
```

Comment: CurrentToolsVersion is not available in ToolLocationHelper class

Comment: @nainaigu: Make sure you're using the `ToolLocationHelper` from `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` and not the one from `Microsoft.Build.Utilities`.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentToolsVersion is not available in ToolLocationHelper class, I am here using V