# MsBuild Task: Register Com Component on remote/deployed-to machine?

Tags: com, msbuild, wmi, registration

I am currently still fiddling with our msbuild & deployment script and one of the steps is to register a (legacy) com component on the machine the code is deployed to. Is there any 'elegant' way to accomplish this or would I have to call the regsvr32.exe via wmi on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PsExec (from formerly SysInternals - but now part of Microsoft)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to execute shell commands on remote machines.

Just use a standard MSBuild Exec task that wraps PsExec.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell v2 remoting via an [MSBuild PowerShell task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78069/any-good-powershell-msbuild-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

As part of your build you could create an MSI that installs your COM component (e.g. using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) -- [Votive has msbuild support](http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html)).

Then you'd run the installation on the remote machine by invoking the [Win32_Product.Install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390890%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually perform the COM component registration by using the [StdRegProv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class to 
write to the registry on the remote machine (i.e. create the HKLM\CLSID{guid} entries, etc)