# In MsBuild, how do I run something PowerShell and have all errors reported

Tags: powershell, error-handling, msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-task

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any good PowerShell MSBuild tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78069/any-good-powershell-msbuild-tasks)

Powershell doesn't seem to have an easy way to trigger it with an arbitrary command and then bubble up parse and execution errors in a way that correctly interoperates with callers that are not PowerShell - e.g., `cmd.exe`, [TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647987/how-do-i-get-errors-to-propagate-in-the-teamcity-powershell-runner) etc.

My question is simple. What's the best way for me with OOTB MSBuild v4 and PowerShell v3 (open to suggestions-wouldnt rule out a suitably production ready MSBuild Task, but it would need to be a bit stronger than suggesting "it's easy - taking the PowerShell Task Factory sample and tweak it and/or becoming it's maintainer/parent") to run a command (either a small script segment, or (most commonly) an invocation of a `.ps1` script.

I'm thinking it should be something normal like:

```
<Exec 
  IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"
  Command="PowerShell &quot;$(ThingToDo)&quot;" />
```

---

That sadly doesn't work:-

1. if `ThingToDo` fails to parse, it fails silently
2. if `ThingToDo` is a script invocation that doesn't exist, it fails
3. if you want to propagate an `ERRORLEVEL` based `.cmd` result, it gets hairy
4. if you want to embed `"` quotes in the `ThingToDo`, it won't work

So, what is the bullet proof way of running PowerShell from MSBuild supposed to be? Is there something I can [PsGet](http://psget.net/) to make everything OK?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following example:

```
<InvokeScript Condition="..."
              PowerShellProperties="..."
              ScriptFile="[PATH TO PS1 FILE]"
              Function="[FUNCTION TO CALL IN PS1]"
              Parameters="..."
              RequiredOutputParams="...">
  <!-- You can catch the output in an Item -->
  <Output TaskParameter="OutputResults"
          ItemName="Output" />
</InvokeScript>
```

This can be used in MSBuild.

Comment: I assume you're referring to [a version of Bart de Smet's Task (which currently resides in the MSBuild Extension pack)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3465029/11635)? That's the reason for my semi-weasely OOTB bit in the question

Comment: On reflection, thanks for making me realize this is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12817556/11635 Can you Vote to Close this question please (assuming you agree that is)

Answer (score 1):

Weeeeelll, you could use something long winded like this until you find a better way:-

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <__PsInvokeCommand>powershell "Invoke-Command</__PsInvokeCommand>
  <__BlockBegin>-ScriptBlock { $errorActionPreference='Stop';</__BlockBegin>
  <__BlockEnd>; exit $LASTEXITCODE }</__BlockEnd>
  <_PsCmdStart>$(__PsInvokeCommand) $(__BlockBegin)</PsCmdStart>
  <_PsCmdEnd>$(__BlockEnd)"</PsCmdEnd>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then 'all' you need to do is:

```
<Exec 
  IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"
  Command="$(_PsCmdStart)$(ThingToDo)$(_PsCmdEnd)" />
```

The single redeeming feature of this (other than trapping all error types I could think of), is that it works OOTB with any PowerShell version and any MSBuild version.

I'll get my coat.