# SQL server agent not reporting failure from uncaught exception in PowerShell script

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, error-handling, sql-server-agent

I have set up an SQL server agent job with a few steps that needs to be processed each week. One of which is a PowerShell script that will throw the following (uncaught) custom exception:

```
$endfile = Test-Path "C:\Temp\1_${loc}_${lastpayweek}.csv"
IF ($endfile -eq $true) 
{
   throw "target file already exists"
}
```

Now when this occurs, I can see in the server agent history that an exception was thrown but the step is still reported as a success. Without a failed, the server agent will not send out a notification email to let me know of the failure.

I am calling the PowerShell script like this:

```
powershell C:\scripts\rename_timesheet_export.ps1 -loc 3
```

Why is it reported as a success?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set you $ErrorActionPreference to stop:

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

By default this is set to Continue, so when Powershell is called from SQL Agent the job will continue on error unless you change the setting.

I have a few more tips on calling Powershell from SQL Agent here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/06/10-tips-for-the-sql-server-powershell-scripter.aspx

Comment: I changed my execution to 
try {
    powershell C:\scripts\export_timesheet_csv.ps1 -loc 3 -locid 102 -ErrorAction 'Stop'
}
catch {
    throw $_
}

and inside the script, immediately after receiving the command line params, I am throwing an exception. I get the same scenario where the job reports a success but in the history notes that an exception happened.

Comment: Seems odd that you are call powershell.exe in sqlps job step?

Comment: I removed the powershell.exe call from the front of the execution statement and it started reporting errors correctly. It seems like it was making a powershell call within a powershell (SQL job) call and the exceptions were not being passed all the way through.

Comment: Error handling with Powershell at first takes a little getting used to. The try/catch blocks requires you to set error actions and also doesn't work with legacy (exe's) type commands. Traditional command-line apps set exit codes.

Comment: @ChadMiller I found I had to call powershell.exe in sqlps job step because the powershell version in SQL is 2.0 and I wanted to use invoke-command which is a 3.0 cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your answer:

[Why are my powershell exit codes always "0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777492/why-are-my-powershell-exit-codes-always-0)

a lot of things say using `-file` is the issue but it looks like you aren't