# Returning the correct return code

Tags: exit-code, sccm

I am running the following commandline in a SCCM Task Sequence:

```
%WinDir%\system32\windowsPowershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {.\SAS9.4_Frv1.ps1 Install -Perso:Base}"
```

I tried returning from my script different exit code: `-1 1618`, etc... And everytime I get a return code of `0`.

How may I make my script returning the correct exit code?
from my script, I am returning Exit `-1` or `Exit 1618`.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777492/why-are-my-powershell-exit-codes-always-0/15779295#15779295
Also this may be applicable (it refers to the same Connect issue): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ec5c7b5-4a36-4890-98c2-ae654993f173/powershell-script-startprocess-no-exitcode-when-run-in-sccm-tasksequence?forum=configmanagerapps

Comment: I used LastExitcode and it does solve my issue.