# Error in CAKE task not displayed in TeamCity overview

Tags: c#, powershell, teamcity, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.22.0 and TeamCity 9.x.

In TeamCity, I have only one build step invoking `build.ps1`. In turn, it runs `build.cake`.

In `build.ps1`, I have added the following:

```
trap
{
    write-output $_
    ##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE' ]
    exit 1
}
```

The reason is to circumvent [a known PowerShell bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777492/why-are-my-powershell-exit-codes-always-0) (i.e., executing a script with `-file` returns an exit code of 0 when it shouldn't).

When the exception is thrown within `build.ps1`, TeamCity correctly displays the build failure:

[image]

However, if an error occurs within `build.cake`, TeamCity incorrectly claims that everything ran successfully:

[image]

Here is the corresponding build log for the "successful" build referenced by the screenshot above:

[image]

As you can see, the error was thrown within a `build.cake` task. This error was not captured by the `trap` clause in `build.ps1`, and so TeamCity was not informed of the build failure.

I thought about adding an `OnError` clause to all my tasks in `build.cake` (the clause will contain something similar to `Information(@"Some error message\n##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE']]"`)), but this will lead to a ghastly amount of duplicate code.

Is there a succinct way to ensure that any errors thrown within the tasks in `build.cake` are caught in the `trap` clause in `build.ps1`?

Comment: I think you might be barking up the wrong tree.  The `trap` fix will only help you if your Powershell script is throwing an exception.  When using cake, the PS script is just calling out the the cake executable and returning the exit code Cake returns.  Cake will handle any thrown exceptions from tasks.  In fact your build log says `Process exited with code 1`, which to me says the PS script is returning the correct code, and perhaps your build step is not using the exit code to indicate an error.  I'd check your TeamCity build step.

Comment: @heavyd Thank you for your reply! In my TeamCity build step, the parameter ``Format stderr output as`` is set to ``Warning``. Could this explain why TeamCity displays the build as successful?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken in my original comment, the settings are not on the individual build steps, but in the "Failure Conditions" section of the Build Configuration. [See docs here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Failure+Conditions).  Make sure the `the build process exit code is not zero` is checked.

Comment: @heavyd Thank you for your suggestion. I have checked my failure conditions and ``the build process exit code is not zero`` is indeed checked, so the issue lies elsewhere...

Answer (score 4):

Cake itself builds on TeamCity with these build step settings and build fails when Cake scripts reports an build failure.

**Runner type:** PowerShell

**Step name:** Build Cake

**Execute step:** If all previous steps finished successfully

**PowerShell version:** 3.0

**Platform:** Auto

**Edition:** Desktop

**Format stderr output as:** warning

**Working directory:**

**Script:** Source code

**Script source:**

```
.\build.ps1
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

**Script execution mode:** Execute .ps1 from external file

Screenshot below of our settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have adopted your suggestion and I will report back the next time a build fails -- if the failure is correctly displayed then I will accept your answer. :-)

Comment: Well go ahead an break that build ;)

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, TeamCity continues to claim that failed builds are successful. However, after changing *Format stderr output as* from "warning" to "error", I managed to achieve the result that I want. According to TeamCity's documentation (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/PowerShell), **"To fail a build if 'an error message is logged by build runner' (see Build Failure Conditions), change the default setting of the Error Output selector from warning to error."** If you update your answer to align with TeamCity's documentation I will re-accept it :-) Thank you!