# GitLab Job Passes Despite Non-Zero Exit Code

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab CI/CD Job with the following definition:

```
compile:
  stage: compile
  tags:
    - windows
    - powershell
    - bl653_8dc0_1053
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - main.linenumbers.uwc
  script:
    - XComp_BL653_8DC0_1053.exe .\main.linenumbers.sb
    - Test-Path -Path .\main.linenumbers.uwc
```

When the job executes, the XComp_BL653_8DC0_1053.exe application fails and returns exit code 7.  However, the build still succeeds even though there was a non-zero exit code and no artifacts.

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
$ XComp_BL653_8DC0_1053.exe .\main.linenumbers.sb
OnEvent  EVTMR2              call HandlerTimer2
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compile Error: (0x0453) TOK_UNKNOWN_EVENTFUNC
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File   : main.linenumbers.sb
Line   : 110
Source : OnEvent  EVTMR2              call HandlerTimer2
       : ----------------------------------^
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Version:      14.3.2
Git revision: e0218c92
Git branch:   14-3-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-09-30T16:11:30+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=7216 revision=e0218c92 version=14.3.2
WARNING: main.linenumbers.uwc: no matching files   
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Job succeeded
```

I can see that it never runs the `Test-Path` line, so it is correctly exiting when the non-zero exit code happens, but why is it saying the build passes?

I'm using GitLab EE version 14.9.  My runner is a PowerShell Executer on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is an artifact of how powershell works. The script will continue even if a command fails and the overall exit code for the script (and job) will be the exit code of the last command.

To ensure a command failure in `XComp_BL653_8DC0_1053.exe` causes the job to stop and exit, you would want to do something like:

```yaml
script:
  - | 
    XComp_BL653_8DC0_1053.exe .\main.linenumbers.sb
    if(!$?) { Exit $LASTEXITCODE }
```

You can see this pattern repeated a lot in the [internal powershell scripts used by the runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#powershell).

You can also set the `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` to change this behavior for powershell cmdlets (not necessarily `.exe`s). This can be done in an environment variable:

```yaml
  variables:
    ErrorActionPreference: STOP
```

For additional context, see:

- [How to stop a PowerShell script on the first error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9948517/5747944)
- [Why are my PowerShell exit codes always "0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777492/why-are-my-powershell-exit-codes-always-0)

Comment: Gave this a try and unfortunately, it didn't work.  One thing to note from my question is that the CI/CD job does stop after the XComp.exe exits with a non-zero exit code.  So I don't think it's an issue of powershell not exiting, but of GitLab not recognizing that it exited with a non-zero code.  Even if XComp.exe is my last command, the job still "succeeds"